# Not able to read a file from network share through SSIS job

Tags: ssis

I have configured ssis job through sql agent. I am trying to read from csv file whaich is in the network share, but the execution report saying "The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty."
But there is csv file in that directory

i have given as *.* in the for each container. Please help regarding this.

Using proxy account to execute the job. The proxy account need to have access to this folder? If so, why the job is not failing because of the account not having access, instead saying the file directory is empty

Comment: What does "i have given as . in the for each container. " mean? See here for an example: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx If you are talking about the contents of the _Files_ field, start with `*.*`

Comment: Change your files in the container from . to star \*.\*
That should help.

Comment: If `*.*` works, and you only want to import CSV files, use `*.CSV`

Comment: yeah, i have provided as star+dot+star in the for each container. Still throwing the error

Comment: Which one did you do? `*.*` or `.`. You're not making any sense

Comment: Probably you have the files on your local computer, and you don't realize when the package runs as a job, it looks for the files on the SQL Server itself and not on your local computer.